# JDBC's Resultset is giving me the first row of the query twice. Why?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, resultset

So, this is the code:

```
 ...
 try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_file);
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
  ResultSet rs = null;
  rs = stmt.executeQuery("select order_id from orders where user_id=" + user_id + ";");
  if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() ) {
   System.out.println("no orders");
  } else {
     do {
      System.out.println(rs.getString("order_id"));
     } while (rs.next());
  }
 } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
 ...
```

I tried to execute the query manually on the sqlite db and it's okay, but this code gives me all the results but the first one twice. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

For example, if the db has 3 orders from that user_id, it returns:

```
first
first
second
third
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try `while (rs.next()) {System.out.println(rs.getString("order_id"));}`

Comment: You should always call `rs.next()` _before_ trying to access a record in the result set.  This advances the cursor to the next record.  As to why you can access the first record without `rs.next()`, I don't know why, but you should not be using this pattern.

Comment: Attempting to call `rs.getString()` before calling `rs.next()` should throw an exception. This would indicate a bug in your JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, that was the problem.
I just changed it to:

```
 ...
 try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_file);
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
  ResultSet rs = null;
  rs = stmt.executeQuery("select order_id from orders where user_id=" + user_id + ";");
  if (!rs.next()) {
   System.out.println("no orders");
  } else {
     do {
      System.out.println(rs.getString("order_id"));
     } while (rs.next());
  }
 } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
 ...
```